# When is QCoreApplication valid?

Tags: c++, qt, qcoreapplication

I want to get the application path however when I run the application in Qt Creator, the applicationPath() method returns an empty string:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {   
        QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules("*.info=false\n");
        QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("company name");
        QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain("companydomain.com");
        QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("AppName");

    #ifdef QT_DEBUG
        //Install logging message handler
        Logger::LogManager::setApplicationPath(QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath());
        qInstallMessageHandler(Logger::LogManager::logMsg);
        qDebug() << "built with debug";
    #else
        qDebug() << "built for release";
    #endif
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'll explain the issue even when your actual problem was different.*

`QCoreApplication` computes the file path and the default application name based on the executable. The executable is taken from the [first command-line argument, `argv[0]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024202/1485885).

You must first instantiate the `QCoreApplication` with those arguments (even when they are static, they access an internal singleton which must be initialized).

Actually, Qt gives you a console warning when accessing such methods without any previous instance:

> QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  qDebug() << "applicationFilePath" << QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath();
  qDebug() << "applicationName" << QCoreApplication::applicationName();
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  qDebug() << "applicationFilePath" << QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath();
  qDebug() << "applicationName" << QCoreApplication::applicationName();

  return a.exec();
}
```

Output

```
CoreApplication::applicationFilePath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
applicationFilePath ""
applicationName ""
applicationFilePath "D:/src/stackoverflow/59355035/debug/59355035.exe"
applicationName "59355035"
```

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved this issue name by changing my routine to get the application name as that's really what I needed:

```
    Logger::LogManager::setApplicationName(QCoreApplication::applicationName());
```

Anyway, `QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()` and `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` are available after creation of a `QCoreApplication` instance. If you need to get the application path before creation of a `QCoreApplication` instance, you will need to refer to argv[0] and parse it for your use-case.